# Параллельное умножение матриц OpenMP C++

Tags: c++, openmp, parallel

Здраствуйте, передо мной стоит задача перемножить матрицы без распараллеливания вычислений, с использованиям 2/4/8 потоков, написал код, который представлен Вам ниже, 2 вопроса:

1. Возможно ли задавать не явно число потоков (т.е. условно передавать в функцию кол-во потоков и использовать для распараллеливания + не нужно повторять куски кода)
2. Что я делаю неправильно с циклами и потоками, ибо по логике время
   работы должно уменьшаться, а оно наоборот растет.

Заранее огромное спасибо.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <ctime>

int **create_matrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int **array;
    array = new int *[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        array[i] = new int [cols];
    }
    return array;
}

void fill_matrix(int **array, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = rand()%100;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int rows1,rows2,cols1,cols2;
    while(true)
    {
        printf("Введите размер первой матрицы: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &rows1, &cols1);
        printf("Введите размер второй матрицы: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &rows2, &cols2);
        if (cols1 == rows2){
            break;
        }
        else printf("Умножить матрицу можно только при cols1 == rows2\n");
    }
    int **A_matrix = create_matrix(rows1, cols1);
    int **B_matrix = create_matrix(rows2, cols2);
    fill_matrix(A_matrix, rows1, cols1);
    fill_matrix(B_matrix, rows2, cols2);
    int **Res_matrix = create_matrix(rows1, cols2);
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cols1; k++)
            {
                Res_matrix[i][j] += A_matrix[i][k]*B_matrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (double) (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    clock_t start2 = clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cols1; k++)
            {
                Res_matrix[i][j] += A_matrix[i][k]*B_matrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end2 = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (double) (end2-start2)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    clock_t start3 = clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cols1; k++)
            {
                Res_matrix[i][j] += A_matrix[i][k]*B_matrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end3 = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (double) (end3-start3)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    clock_t start4 = clock();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < cols2; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cols1; k++)
            {
                Res_matrix[i][j] += A_matrix[i][k]*B_matrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end4 = clock();
    printf("%f\n", (double) (end4-start4)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Comment: Стоит уточнить, о матрицах каких размеров идет речь.

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли задавать не явно число потоков (т.е. условно передавать в функцию кол-во потоков и использовать для распараллеливания + не нужно повторять куски кода)

Возможно и всё элементарно; надо просто: указать в прагме переменную.

```
size_t num;
// ..
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num)
for (int i = 0; i < rows1; i++){ /* ... */ }
```

> Что я делаю неправильно с циклами и потоками, ибо по логике время работы должно уменьшаться, а оно наоборот растет.

`clock()` измеряет *процессорное время* работы всего процесса, т.е. оно равно сумме времени работы каждого отдельного потока. А т.к. общий объём работ не меняется + появляются накладные расходы на паралелизацию, то оно может немного увеличиваться.

Нужно использовать измерять *реальное время*. Например, с помощью тех инструментов, которые предоставляет [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) или системных средств, как например, [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`](https://ru.manpages.org/clock_gettime/2) на POSIX-системах.